# Using update with an inner join SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed som guidance as to how I can retrieve a column needed from a table with an `INNER JOIN` and in the same time update and insert a new column  into my original table.

This is what I have written so far

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 

            a.[CustNo],
            X.CustomerID    

  FROM tblA_Add_CustomerID_Column a
  INNER JOIN tblX x
    ON x.CustomerCode = a.custno
```

My Table, `tblA_Add_CustomerID_Column`, only has a column named `CustNo`, and with the above query, I want to add `CustomerID` to Table, `tblA_Add_CustomerID_Column`.

How can I `UPDATE` and `INSERT` the column `CustomerID` from the table `tblX`?

My normal approach has always been doing the `INNER JOIN` , then take the results onto the excel sheet, and then import my excel file to the DB.

Comment: what about using temp tables instead of excel sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the column with something like

`alter table tblA_Add_CustomerID_Column  add CustomerID int`

then you can update the table using an update statement, something like

```
UPDATE tblA_Add_CustomerID_Column  
SET CustomerID = x.cusomterID
FROM tblX x
WHERE custno = x.CustomerCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead:

```
ALTER TABLE tblA_Add_CustomerID_Column
ADD CustomerID INT;

EXEC('
UPDATE a
        SET CustomerID = x.cusomterID
        FROM tblA_Add_CustomerID_Column a
        INNER JOIN tblX x ON x.CustomerCode = a.custno;
    ');
```